# Automating mat-option in testcafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Tried automating dropdown using the below methods but the dropdown values couldn't be selected.

Method 1:

```
const comboOption = Selector("mat-option").child("span").withExactText("Hello");
await t.click(comboOption);
```

Method 2:

```
ClientFunction(() => {
  document.getElementsByClassName('mat-option-text')[0].innerText = 'Hello';
  document.getElementsByClassName('mat-option-text')[0].click();
  return "Hello";});
```

The mat-option tag is not within mat-select. It is outside mat-select and within div tag.
Are there other ways to achieve automating mat-option ?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the code snippets.

As far as I understand, you are trying to click an option element in another select element.
I created a simple test that should perform the steps you described:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture`Getting Started`
    .page`http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example`;
const selectElement = Selector('#preferred-interface');
const optionElement = selectElement.find('option');

test('My first test', async t => {
    await t
    .click(selectElement)
    .click(optionElement.withText('Both'))
    .expect(selectElement.value).eql('Both');
});
```

If I misunderstood your question, could you please share a simple example of your .html and a detailed description of
what you want to do in the test and which results you expect?